# Media query on html

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, background-image

Is there a way to use media query on html? I need to put a image like a banner centralized on my page, when the screen it's less than 768px it's shows a smaller image but when the screen grows to more than 768px it should replace the smaller image to another image that I have that is bigger. Is there a way to make this only on html and inline css? I should'nt use an external file.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad and you haven't shown your attempt. Also, media queries and picture elements have been discussed at exceptional length on SO and elsewhere. The most meager research would've answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using inline CSS:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="small-banner.jpg" alt="Small Banner" style="max-width: 100%;">

  <style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      img {
        content: url(large-banner.jpg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not inline CSS. It's an _embedded_ style element. There's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `div` which has a `background-image` instead of the `img` element. Then you can add a media query in CSS where you define a smaller size and a different `background-image` for the mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do in one file, in html, it is not possible to do in img tag. But you can do something like this, using embedded style element. For example:

```
<html>
   ...
   <style>
      .large-img {
        display: none;
      }
      .small-img {
        display: block;
      }
      @media(min-width: 768px) {
        .large-img {
          display: block;
        }
        .small-img {
          display: none;
        }
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      ...
      <img class="large-img" src="largeImage.png">
      <img class="small-img" src="smallImage.png">
      ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use CSS for this. Use the [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element; it is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/picture) by modern browsers:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="path/to/bigger/picture"
    media="(min-width: 768px)"
  >
  <img src="path/to/smaller/picture">
</picture>
```

Try it:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="https://picsum.photos/700"
    media="(min-width: 768px)"
  >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400">
</picture>
```